# Swift - Programmatically creating Views Issue, unable to find stored property

Tags: ios, view, swift

I am trying to learn Swift and iOS Views and ViewControllers.

```
var window: UIWindow?
var rootViewController: MyCustomView?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.rootViewController = MyCustomView()
    self.rootViewController!.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    var rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)
    var label = UILabel(frame: rect)
    label.text = "Hello iOS Views"
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    self.window!.rootViewController = self.rootViewController
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
```

I am getting an error when I compile, ***"Could not find member 'rootViewController'"*** on the following line:

```
self.window!.rootViewController = self.rootViewController
```

Not sure why Xcode 6 Beta is not liking it but it's able to find this line:

```
self.rootViewController!.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about properties. Do you understand the difference between self.window.rootViewController and self.rootViewController?

Comment: @CHBuckingham Irrelevant.

Comment: Why do you need a local variable to hold the rootViewController? Do you need it somewhere else in the AppDelegate?

Comment: @dasdom No particular reason, I was learning to write views programmatically in swift like I did in Objective-C. The 'same' code works in Objective C but not in Swift. Not sure why the compiler is choking on that line possible due to it being Beta not sure.

Comment: I have no answer to this, but in general, if you don't need the code, delete it. Code is written once but read hundred times. Less code, less burden.

Comment: @matt unfortunately XCode 6 Beta only reports 1 error in the error log and that is it. Again this is throw away code it was meant for me as learning purposes but it peaked my interest. I will attempt to re-write the same piece of code when XCode 6 and iOS8 is finally released.

Comment: @TheLazyChap That's okay, I solved it for you.

Comment: @matt not sure what you think is irrelevant, but the core of the issue is the two properties I point out. A little more investigation and you'll see the mismatch in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that MyCustomView is a UIView. But UIWindow's `rootViewController` expects a UIViewController.

Generally you have confused yourself right through your code by not distinguishing view controllers from views. But you did name MyCustomView sensibly, which is good. The fact that it has a `backgroundColor` helps to prove that it is a view, not a view controller (view controllers have no background color).

Comment: The Swift compiler error message here could definitely be improved. "Attempt to assign a UIView to a UIViewController property" would have been nice! Even "Type mismatch" would be better than just claiming that the property is missing.

Comment: right on matt, good catch. I guess I've been coding for too long tonight. Thanks.